# Environment variable for JETTY_HOME not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I added an environment variable for jetty following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994031/215094) but I still get `JETTY_HOME not set` error:

```
root@b:/opt# echo $JETTY_HOME
/opt/jetty
root@b:/opt# service jetty start
** ERROR: JETTY_HOME not set, you need to set it or install in a standard location
root@b:/opt#
```

This is how my `/etc/environment` looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games":
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java":
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather frustrating error with little help out there. I thought I'd post my solution here for someone who is looking to solve the same problem.

Anyway, the correct solution is to set `JETTY_HOME` in `/etc/default/jetty` like so:

```
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty
```

Hope this helps someone.

PS: This is jetty 9 on Ubuntu 14.04 over Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the service, but  in general these things work by forking, i.e. by creating another shell. When this happens, the new shell does not inherit the locally set shell variables, *except* for those that are explicitly singled out for this. This is done by means of the command `export`, so you should modify your command into:

```
    export JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty
```

and likewise for al variables that you want you subshells, and daughters to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem I had was that I created the "/opt/jetty" file in windows first as a text file and then I FTP'd it over to the server. This was not being recognized because it was apparently some sort of "dos format", so when I deleted the file and remade it using:

```
nano /etc/default/jetty
```

and pasted the variable info in that way, it suddenly all worked!